# Combine two tables with same Primary key

Tags: mysql

This seems like a simple question but I can't seem to find an answer. I have two tables. Table 1:

```js
+---------+-----------+--------+-------+----------+
| userid  | username  | date   | time  | footsize |
+---------+-----------+--------+-------+----------+
|       1 | user1     | 103999 |  1010 |        9 |
|       2 | user2     | 484883 |   984 |        6 |
+---------+-----------+--------+-------+----------+
```

and Table 2:

```js
+---------+-----------+----------+
| userid  | natural   | synthetic| 
+---------+-----------+----------+
|       1 | y         | n        | 
|       2 | n         | y        | 
+---------+-----------+----------+
```

What I'd like to do is delete table 2. 
But I need to move the columns and data `natural` and `synthetic` from `table 2` and insert them into `table 1`, using `userid` as a primary key to make sure the data goes to the right customer.

I tried using the join statements but I can't seem to move them from joining to inserting without an error.

The general (loose) idea I want is

```
select userid from table1, select * from table2. 
Insert into table1, table2.natural, table2.synthetic where table1.userid = table2.userid;
```

So that table 1 looks like this:

```js
    +---------+-----------+--------+-------+----------+-----------+----------+
    | userid  | username  | date   | time  | footsize | natural   | synthetic| 
    +---------+-----------+--------+-------+----------+-----------+----------+
    |       1 | user1     | 103999 |  1010 |        9 | y         | n        | 
    |       2 | user2     | 484883 |   984 |        6 | n         | y        | 
    +---------+-----------+--------+-------+----------+-----------+----------+
```

I'm aware that's not a real query, but it should clarify what I'm trying to do. Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) - or just wait for GL to rock up.

Comment: Edited for clarity.

Comment: Nope. Just edited.

Comment: sigh. Well, that's the best I can do with my limited talent. What part is unclear?

Comment: What part of the accepted answer at the linked question provided is unclear?

Comment: The only difference I gathered was that I didn't make the tables look like pictures, but being that it was a very simple table I didn't see that it helped. However, i have now made the tables pretty in hopes that it clarifies the goal.

Comment: I'm sorry; I'm not sure what more I can add to the detailed advice already provided.

Comment: Well I figured it out in a slow way, column by column, by first creating the columns in table1. Then I ran this:


UPDATE table1 n
JOIN table2 nic ON n.useridl = nic.userid
SET n.natural = nic.natural;

Then I did the same, changing Natural to synthetic.

Answer (score 0):

- first you create a table that has all the columns

  ```
  CREATE TABLE `table3` (
  `userid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `date` INT NULL,
  `time` INT NULL,
  `footsize` INT NULL,
  `natural` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `synthetic` VARCHAR(45) NULL, 
   PRIMARY KEY (`userid`));



  insert into table3
  select t1.userid, t1.username, t1.`date`, t1.`time`, t1.footsize,
  t2.natural, t2.synthetic
  from table1 as t1
  join table2 as t2 
  on t1.userid = t2.userid
  ```